# determine whether the improper integrals converge or not

Tags: calculus

How to determine whether the  improper integrals converge or not?
$$\int_0^{1/2} \frac{x^{4/3}}{x+\ln(1-x)}dx$$ 
I am trying to use the data comparison theory to compute $\int\lim \limits_{x \to 0}$ $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$. How can I determine $f(x)$ and $g(x)$? Are there any other ways to determine improper integrals converge

Answer (score 0):

The integral converges. Look at the power series expansion of $$\ln(1 - x) = -x - x^2/2 - x^3/3 -\cdots$$

So, 
$$x + \ln(1 - x) = -x^2/2 - x^3/3 - x^4/4 -\cdots$$

Let $I$ be the improper integral in question, and consider $J = -I$. Clearly $J$ converges $\iff$ I

converges. We now study $J$.

We have, 
$$\frac{x^{4/3}}{-x - \ln(1 - x)} = \frac{x^{4/3}}{(x^2/2 + x^3/3 + \cdots}) < \frac{2x^{4/3}}{x^2} = 2x^{-2/3}$$ since $0 < x < 1/2 < 1$.

Thus 
$$J < \int_0^{1/2}2x^{-2/3}dx = 6\times2^{-1/3}.$$

So J converges and hence I converges.